# why Changing in numpy array change tensor that converted from numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, converters

When I convert a numpy array to tensor and change the numpy in differnet ways some change the tensor and some not. it is sample:

in this code:

```
array = np.arange(1., 8.)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(array)
array, tensor
```

the answer is :

```
(array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.]),
 tensor([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.], dtype=torch.float64))
```

No when I add 1 to numpy array in this way it change tensor values:

```
array = np.arange(1., 8.)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(array)
array += 1
array, tensor
```

The output is:

```
(array([2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.]),
 tensor([2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.], dtype=torch.float64))
```

But when I change numpy array in another way it dos not change tensor:

```
array = np.arange(1., 8.)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(array)
array = array + 1
array, tensor
```

the output is :

```
(array([2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.]),
 tensor([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.], dtype=torch.float64))
```

again this code dos not change it:

```
array = np.arange(1., 8.)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(array)
array = array + 1
array += 1
array, tensor
```

This also happened when changing pytorch's tensor to numpy array.

Why this way work numpy and torch?

Comment: What you're seeing there happens with other objects as well. `array = array + 1` MUST create a brand new object and store it in `array`.  That doesn't change the original array, which is hooked in torch.  But `array += 1` is a special method, so numpy knows it can just modify the array in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **TL;DR:**

`+=` modifies in place but `x = x + 1` creates a copy.

## **Long version:**

You may want to read about pinned memory. I suspect PyTorch is using it to reduce data transfer overheads for better performance. When you re-assign using `array = array + 1` a copy is created (you can try printing the address of the array using `id(array)` to check if the address is changed after the assignment, meaning a copy is made). When a copy is made, `array` and `tensor` no longer point to the same memory address, so modifying `array` no longer updates the pinned memory.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(3)
print((arr, id(arr)))
arr+=1
print((arr, id(arr)))
arr = arr + 1
print((arr, id(arr)))
```

which (for me) results in:

```
(array([0, 1, 2]), 1951948494416)
(array([1, 2, 3]), 1951948494416)
(array([2, 3, 4]), 1952052860880)
```

When you create a copy, the old array is still being used by the GPU so it remains there (memory isn't freed) so you can still access its old content (check pass by reference vs pass by value).